# Which episode is the "double facepalm" image macro from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

There's a [Demotivational-style image macro](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/demotivational-posters) that features Picard and Riker facepalming at the same time:

[image: Double facepalm of Picard and Riker]

I believe the person in the left of the picture may not be Picard in the original scene: the picture of Picard that you see here was probably photoshopped from [another scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh4Wk.jpg). But what is the source of the original screen capture?

Comment: I love that picture.  Every time I see it, it makes me laugh.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're right that the Picard in this screenshot is shopped in - you can see the original Riker-only facepalm on Google images search.

However, none of those image results indicate where this screen-grab came from.

But - I think that this is from Season 3's "[A Matter of Perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Matter_of_Perspective)" - where Riker is accused of murdering a scientist.

Comment: That seems very plausible, thanks!

Comment: There's an actual double facepalm in Voyager where Q calls himself as a witness and both of him facepalm in response to some statement by Tuvok. Funny that they didn't use that one for the meme.

Comment: @k_g Probably just because TNG is much more iconic.

Answer (score 42):

HorusKol is correct. Here is the original (or near enough to it):

[image: Original image from A Matter of Perspective S3E14]

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the original Picture is from "A Matter of Perspective", while Picard is shopped in from "Deja Q".